# What de Rham cohomology has to do with the Leibniz law?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, de-rham-cohomology

In a [lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VuFCRFKiWvA&list=PLTBqohhFNBE_09L0i-lf3fYXF5woAbrzJ&index=6)(see after 0:09:00 in the video) by Dr. Tadashi Tokieda on topology and geometry, it is being argued by him that, if we have two manifolds $M$ and $N$ with dimensions $m,n$ and boundaries $\partial M, \partial N$  respectively, then the boundary $\partial (M\times N)$ of the product manifold $M\times N$, is given by
$$\partial (M\times N)=(\partial M \times N)\cup (M\times \partial N)$$
He continues to argue that the boundary operator $\partial$ acts like Leibniz law for differentiation and claims that the analogy has something to do with the so called "de Rham cohomology"

My question: What is the connection between Leibniz law , boundary operator and the de Rham cohomology?

Comment: Tokieda is anticipating on some formulas that will occur when regarding integration of top forms on oriented manifolds. The reference to Leibniz rule is an analogy: replacing $\partial$ with $'$, $\cup$ with $+$ and $M,N$ with $f,g$, you surely recognize $(fg)' = f'g + fg'$

Comment: Be careful, though. $M\times N$ is a manifold with corners when both $M$ and $N$ have boundary.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46252/is-the-boundary-partial-s-analogous-to-a-derivative) MO post?

Comment: @HallaSurvivor I was exactly looking for insights like the one in that question.  Thanks for pointing to that thread.